# Increase font size in rxvt-unicode without editing ~/.Xdefaults

Tags: fonts, rxvt

I am a loyal Linux fan who has been spending a lot of time using iTerm on a mac lately.  One thing I *really* like about the mac, and iTerm in particular, is the ability to use a keyboard shortcut to in/decrease the font size.  I believe it's apple+ and apple- to do this. AFAIK this is also possible using gnome-terminal and possibly konqueror.

However, I am an rxvt-unicode user.  Period.  I'm not willing to switch my terminal, but I would like to be able to have the ability to quickly resize the font.  Currently, to resize the font I have to do this:

1. Detach tmux
2. $EDITOR ~/.Xdefaults
3. xrdb -all ~/.Xdefaults
4. close terminal
5. open a new terminal
6. Reattach tmux

I'm thinking that it must be possible to script something that would reduce the above steps to one by perhaps binding to a keyboard shortcut, maybe with xbindkeys or something similar.  Anyone have any thoughts on how this might best be accomplished?

Note:  I'm using awesome window manager and prefer to keep things ultra-simple (i.e., no Gnome/KDE-specific solutions, please).

@Keith: I am familiar with the escape sequences and it's my fault for not saying so explicitly in my original question, but:  I'm looking for a solution that will persist between sessions.  Likely that will involve writing some code.

Comment: Here's another one I am using now. All credit goes to the author. https://github.com/simmel/urxvt-resize-font

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one that works, and is persistent between sessions:

https://github.com/noah/urxvt-font

Answer (score 16):

From the man page:

> CHANGING FONTS
>          Changing fonts (or font sizes, respectively) via the keypad is not
>   yet supported in rxvt-unicode. Bug me
>   if you
>          need this.
>
> ```
>    You can, however, switch fonts at runtime using escape sequences,
> ```
>
> e.g.:
>
> ```
>       printf '\e]710;%s\007' "9x15bold,xft:Kochi Gothic"
>
>    You can use keyboard shortcuts, too:
>
>       URxvt.keysym.M-C-1: command:\033]710;suxuseuro\007\033]711;suxuseuro\007
>       URxvt.keysym.M-C-2: command:\033]710;9x15bold\007\033]711;9x15bold\007
>
>    rxvt-unicode will automatically re-apply these fonts to the output so
> ```
>
> far.

Depending on the shell you use you could assign those to keyboard shortcuts. In zsh you could define a shell function and use bindkey to bind it to an alt-key for example.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this will not persist, right?

Comment: Sure it will. The keysym shortcuts you put in your ~/.Xdefaults file. If you use the shell functions and keybindings you put those in your ~/.zshrc (or whatever) file.

Comment: I think we are defining "persist" differently.  Your proposed solution of echoing escape sequences *will not* persist in a new process (new terminal window).  See my (accepted) answer below for a solution that does "persist" in the sense that it outlives its parent process.